# Use theme with style, selector and attr on Android

Tags: android, styles, themes, selector, attr

I try to change text color with theme in a selector but i have already the same color : #fff (i havent this color in my colors.xml !)

Here is my selector.xml (in drawable/) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:color="?attr/tabsTextColor" />
</selector>
```

My attrs.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="tabsTextColor" format="color" />
</resources>
```

Colors.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- ... -->
    <color name="tabs_text_color">#ff0</color>
</resources>
```

And my theme.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@style/Theme.GreenDroid.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="tabsTextColor">@color/tabs_text_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I dont understant because text color is in red (get #f00 with photoshop) but not #ff00 !

Where is the mistake? Thanks

**EDIT :** I replace in my layout

```
android:textColor="@drawable/selector.xml"
```

By

```
android:textColor="?attr/tabsTextColor"
```

And the color is good ! I can't use selector with theme attr ?

Answer (score 15):

You cannot reference theme attrs within in a selector, but what you can do is create multiple selectors which each only reference color/drawable resources, and then use a reference attr to control which selector is used in your theme

Comment: Simple and genius. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to use this method for tinting a single vector to multiple tints as needed, for API < 21 devices?

Comment: If anybody is wondering; the theme attribute has to be of type reference e.g. <attr name="selectorText" format="reference" />

Comment: @AustrianDude can you give an example of how to make a selector for each theme but with the same name?

Comment: @R.F In my above case the different themes have been set in the theme.xml in the following way: 

<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="selectorText">@drawable/selector_text</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseTheme.NightMode" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
<item name="selectorText">@drawable/selector_text_inverse</item>
</style>

Answer (score -4):

**First:**
Problem is with your color en-coding.
Color is specified as a combination of `RGB` (Red, Green, Blue) where as in photoshop `0xff00` means its a 16bit/15bit color whose first byte has `0xFF` value which would have red component but not red exactly..

Now for android many other things are specified in it. a color is encoded as `ARGB` whre it is Alpha, Red Green Blue so the color value for opaque red would be `0xFFFF0000`. Color in Android is 32bit Value.

**Second:**
`android:textColor="?attr/tabsTextColor"` accepts a color value. Passing selector is wrong.

**Third**
Every item in seletor should have a reference to a drawable. Where is that?
You should have a drawable in your selecter as in somethingselector.xml.
`<item
android:state_focused="false"

android:state_selected="false"

android:state_pressed="false"

android:drawable="@drawable/something" />`

So in your code you can use like this `android:drawableRight="@drawable/somethingseletor"`